# GUI-based credit card checker

Tags: java, validation, swing, e-commerce

How can I make this more readable, faster, and make the GUI more appealing?

**`CreditCard` class:**

```
import java.util.*;
public class CreditCards {

    private String prefix;
    private String length;

    public CreditCards(String p, String l) {

        prefix = p;
        length = l;

    }

    public String getPrefix() {
        return prefix;
    }

    public String getLength() {
        return length;
    }
}
```

**`MasterCard` class:**

```
public class MasterCard extends CreditCards {

    public MasterCard(String prefix,String length) {
        super(prefix,length);
    }

    public boolean isMaster() {
        boolean pre = (getPrefix().equals("55") || getPrefix().equals("51"))? true:false;
        boolean len = getLength().equals("16")? true:false;

        if(pre && len) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**`VisaCard` class:**

```
public class VisaCard extends CreditCards {

    public VisaCard(String pre,String len) {
        super(pre,len);
    }

    public boolean isVisa() {
        boolean pre = getPrefix().equals("4") ? true:false;
        boolean len = (getLength().equals("16") || getLength().equals("13"))? true:false;

        if(pre && len) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**GUI:**

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class cardValidatorGUI{
    JFrame frame;
    JTextField cardNumField;
    JComboBox creditCardBox;
    JButton checkButton;
    JButton clearButton;
    String[] cards = {"Visa","Mastercard"};
    String selected = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        cardValidatorGUI r1 = new cardValidatorGUI();
        r1.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel cardPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        cardPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));

        creditCardBox = new JComboBox(cards);

        cardNumField = new JTextField("",20);

        checkButton = new JButton("check");
        checkButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                String selected = creditCardBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if (checkCriteria(selected)){
                    if (checkSum(cardNumField.getText())) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Credit Card is Valid");
                    }
                    else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Credit Card is Not Valid");

                    }
                }
                else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Credit Card is Not Valid");
                }
            }
        });

        clearButton = new JButton("clear");

        cardPanel.add(creditCardBox);
        cardPanel.add(cardNumField);

        buttonPanel.add(checkButton);
        buttonPanel.add(clearButton);

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,cardPanel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,buttonPanel);
        frame.setSize(250, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static boolean checkSum(String check){
        int sum = 0;
        String trimCheck = check.replaceAll(" ", "");
        String reverse = new StringBuffer(trimCheck).reverse().toString();
        for(int i =0;i<trimCheck.length();i++) {
            int checkThis = Character.digit(reverse.charAt(i), 10);

            if(i%2==0) {
                sum+=checkThis;
            }
            else {
                sum += checkThis *2;
                if(checkThis >=5) {
                    sum-=9;
                }
            }
        }
        if(sum%10==0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean checkCriteria(String c) {
        int length = cardNumField.getText().replaceAll(" ","").length();
        String len = Integer.toString(length);

        if (c.equals("Mastercard")) {
            String pre = cardNumField.getText().substring(0,2);
            MasterCard masters = new MasterCard(pre,len);

            if(masters.isMaster()) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        if (c.equals("Visa")) {
            String pre = cardNumField.getText().substring(0,1);
            VisaCard visa = new VisaCard(pre,len);

            if (visa.isVisa()) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Construction like

   ```
   boolean pre = getPrefix().equals("4") ? true:false;
   ```

   is redundant. The following is ok:

   ```
   boolean pre = getPrefix().equals("4");
   ```

   just as

   ```
   if(pre && len) {
       return true;
   }
   return false;
   ```

   this could be just:

   ```
   return pre && len;
   ```
2. Try to avoid 'magic numbers' like 55 or 4. Extract them as constants and give them a proper name.
3. I don't think that you need to operate with `length` as a `String`.
4. Use error dialog for invalid credit card number:

   ```
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Your Credit Card is Valid", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
   ```

   and also use a parent frame as an argument, not `null`.
5. I'd suggest to remove methods `isViza()` and `isMaster()` and add abstract `isValid()` method to `CreditCard` class and override it in both subclasses.
6. Text on your buttons should start with the capital letter.
7. Avoid method names like `go()`. You could name it like `initUI()`.

Comment: btw, I made length as a String for removing the whitespaces. Can you give me an alternative?

Comment: just try to parse it before using in other methods. By the way, you can restrict user to input letters - only digits. Here is the sample code for custom `JTextField`: http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/14311